# Horizontally aligning 2 blocks (one left floated)

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'd like to horizontally align (for whatever screen resolution) the 2 main blocks.
One has a float:left.

If I set margin-left:auto to .site (main content block, at the right), it gets horizontally aligned. The problem is that I don't know how to have the sidebar (the block at the left) aligned too. It's difficult because I need to be sure that the menu gets perfectly "attached" to the content block (so I can't use position:relative;left:XXpx because it changes on different resolutions).

Any ideas? :)

EDIT: If possible, solutions that work with IE 7-8 too (unfortunately) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something here, but you just want to get 2 block elements and make them center-aligned horizontally?

Just wrap them in another div and align that wrapper div with `margin: 0 auto`.

Check [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/fabio_silva/WwvN7/).

```
<div id="#wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
Of course that you have to float the Content div as well (and not only the Sidebar)